# ffmpeg sequence starting at frame 1001

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image sequence starting at 1001 that I'd like to convert to a mp4 using ffmpeg. Here's what I'm putting in cmd shell:

```
ffmpeg -i plates_sh01_%04d.jpeg start_number 1001 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -b:v 4M -pix_fmt yuv420p plates_sh01_%04d.mp4
```

This works for image sequences starting at frame numbers below 999. For any sequence starting at 1000 or above I get this error:

> Could find no file with path 'plates_sh01_%04d.jpeg' and index in the range 0-4
> plates_sh01_%04d.jpeg_%04d.jpeg: No such file or directory

I can't find any solutions to this apart from re-number the image sequence.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-start_number` is an input option. Move it before the `-i`.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense but didn't work. I'll experiment some more

Comment: Show the actual command of your latest attempt, and make sure to use `-start_number`, not `start_number` as shown in your command. Also, your output is going to literally be named `plates_sh01_%04d.mp4`. I think you meant `plates_sh01.mp4`.

Comment: Thanks llogan, ill have another try and report back

Comment: ok, minor success, I can make an mp4 for the first frame but the rest of the sequence is ignored:
ffmpeg -i F:\primaryVFX\PROJECTS\SPECTRUM\3_shots\shoot01\sh01\2d\renders\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01_1001.png -framerate 25 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -b:v 4M -pix_fmt yuv420p F:\primaryVFX\PROJECTS\SPECTRUM\3_shots\shoot01\sh01\2d\renders\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01\mp4\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01.mp4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot `-start_number`, `-framerate` is an input option, and you didn't use a name pattern for the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). Use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -start_number 1001 -i F:\primaryVFX\PROJECTS\SPECTRUM\3_shots\shoot01\sh01\2d\renders\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01_%04d.png -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -vf "scale=1920:-2,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart F:\primaryVFX\PROJECTS\SPECTRUM\3_shots\shoot01\sh01\2d\renders\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01\mp4\spectrum_sh01__layer_bg__v01.mp4
```

Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).